# What's wrong with this MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

what's wrong with this MySQL query?

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\wamp\www\port\gurantee\upload\".$_FILES['userfile']['name']."' INTO TABLE dramexchange.gurantee FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";
```

and give this error:

Parse error: parse error, expecting T_STRING' orT_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING' in C:wampwwwportguranteerec.php on line 13

TnXx

Comment: have you spelt guarantee wrong here: dramexchange.gurantee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would help:

```
'C:\\wamp\\www\\port\\gurantee\\upload\\'
```

Comment: This problem solved, i use double Backslash escapes characters, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Backslash escapes characters...

Comment: This problem solved, i use double Backslash escapes characters, Thanks